# BI Publisher how to use <?fo:page-number?> in an IF condition

Tags: bi-publisher

In a BI report I need to display or hide a certain field based on the page number. For example, if page number = 1 then the field must be hidden. Can you please tell me how to use the  tag as part of an IF condition ?

Answer (score 1):

To end on an even page with layout:

Insert the following syntax in a form field in your template:

```
<?section:force-page-count;'end-on-even-layout'?>
```

To end on an odd page layout:

```
<?section:force-page-count;'end-on-odd-layout'?>
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12844_01/doc/bip.1013/e12187/T421739T481157.htm

Answer (score 0):

As per the Oracle forum, that question was asked a lot and it is not possible to place a condition on a variable that is at the last step of the PDF generation: [Oracle forum](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/864368).

The best way when you want to have different page content is to use sections: [Oracle forum](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2584842).